# If Condition include meta-data in Android manifest file

Tags: java, android, razorpay

I am implementing Razorpay payment integration in Android. I need to diffentiate the live key in the manifest file based the state. but I dont know how to write the condition in androidmanifest file. could you please anyone guide me to do this task.I am sharing my source code also. The below condition is not working

public void startPayment() {

```
    double finalMoney = Double.parseDouble(money);

    finalMoney = finalMoney * 100;

    final Activity activity = this;
    final Checkout checkout = new Checkout();


    try {

        JSONObject preFill = new JSONObject();
        preFill.put("email",email);
        preFill.put("contact",mobile);

        JSONObject options = new JSONObject();
        options.put("name", "mycompany");
        options.put("description", "mysongs");
        options.put("image", "image.png");
        options.put("currency", "INR");
        options.put("amount", finalMoney);
        options.put("prefill",preFill);
        checkout.open(activity,options);

    }
    catch(Exception e) {

        Log.e(TAG,"Error in starting Razorpay Checkout",e);
        mDialog.hide();

    }

}



if (state == "Andhra Pradesh"){

 checkout.setKeyID("rzp_live_2HZ1cIu");


                    }

                    else if (state == "Telangana") {
                        checkout.setKeyID("rzp_live_ZPfUDVl");

                    }

                    startPayment();
                }
```

Comment: try to put **equalsIgnoreCase** like :  `if (state.equalsIgnoreCase("Andhra Pradesh"))`

Comment: I am getting this error: Please set your Razorpay API key in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357619/whether-it-is-possible-to-change-the-android-manifest-attribute-dynamically#answer-7357651) might be help you.